# Function returns but does not do what I asked for

Tags: c

I have a homerwork to do and have this part of code which returns with a 1 but does not adds the m to the b. Any idea what did i miss?

```
int uj_esemeny(meccs m, bajnoksag b){
    int cs1l=0;
    int cs2l=0;
    int temp=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<b.csapatsz;i++){
        if(b.csapatok[i].azon==m.cs1.azon||b.csapatok[i].azon==m.cs2.azon){
            temp++;
        }
    }
    if((b.csapatsz+temp)>6){ return 0;}
    for(i=0;i<b.jatszott;i++){
        if(b.meccsek[i].cs1.azon==m.cs1.azon && b.meccsek[i].cs2.azon==m.cs2.azon)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<b.csapatsz;i++)
    {
        if(b.csapatok[i].azon==m.cs1.azon){cs1l++;}
        if(b.csapatok[i].azon==m.cs2.azon){cs2l++;}
    }
    if(cs1l>0&&cs2l>0){return 0;}
    b.csapatok[b.csapatsz++]=m.cs1;
    b.csapatok[b.csapatsz++]=m.cs2;

    b.meccsek[b.jatszott++]=m;
    return 1;
}
```

```
typedef struct
{
    char azon[10];
    int hasznos;
}csapat;

typedef struct
{
  csapat cs1;
  csapat cs2;
  int cs1gol;
  int cs2gol;
}meccs;

typedef struct
{
  meccs meccsek[30];
  csapat csapatok[6];
  int csapatsz;
  int jatszott;
}bajnoksag;
```

in main `uj_esemeny(m01,b1)`

little translation:
This is about a soccer championship which store matches that are played by teams and we store teams and the results and each individual match.

"csapat" is team
"meccs" is match
"bajnokság" is championship
"cs1" is team1
"cs2" is team2
"cs1gol" is team1 score
"cs2gol" is team2 score

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: `b` is passed by value to this function, meaning: the caller's argument for `b` will *not* be changed. If ever there was an example of solving a problem with a debugger, this is it.

Comment: Can you please add part of code that explains what is ```meccs``` and ```bajnoksag```

Comment: How can we know what it "was asked" for?

Comment: @WhozCraig: `b.csapatok` appears to be an array or pointer, so even if `b` itself cannot be changed when `b` is passed by value, the memory pointed to by `b.csapatok` absolutely *can* be changed. Passing `b` by value is not (necessarily) a bug here.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'll believe that when I see it.

Comment: @DanielPryden: An array in a structure is still in the structure and is passed by value (copy) as part of the structure.

Comment: Perhaps using more reasonable and meaningful variable names would help a great deal

Comment: @EricPostpischil His point is, if `csapatok` and `meccsek` are dynamic pointers instead of fixed arrays, this can (and will) modify host data even when `b` is passed by value. Of course, changes to `csapatsz` and `jatszott` members will *not* be retained, making the workflow of this little gem utterly broken, but it is still not entirely out of the realm of possibility. Without type data (ideally an [mcve]) will never know, and literally only guess.

Comment: Yeah, what WhozCraig said. I'm not saying I'm *recommending* passing `b` by value, just that it might not be the cause of the bug here (but, indeed, it might). Hard to say without an actual MCVE.

Comment: @EdHeal The names are perfectly sensible, they're just in Hungarian.

Comment: @WhozCraig: There are clearly members of `b` being modified in ways intended to survive the function return (because they are made in a code path where they can have no effect unless they survive). Therefore, the statement “Passing `b` by value is not (necessarily) a bug here” is false. Further, the implication that if `b.csapatok` is an array, which is specifically listed as a possibility distinct from being a pointer, that the memory pointed to by it can be changed is incorrect to the extent it implies such changes are outside the copy or can endure the function return.

Comment: @zwol - Is `cs1l` a sensible name?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You are completely correct about the array case, thank you. I still wouldn't rule out the pointer case, but I think you have convinced me that it is *probably* a bug for `b` to be passed by value in this code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I concur. The scalar members are clearly not going to be retained, and are probably critical. At a minimum that's a bug. Whether the data from the sequence members is retained (intentional or otherwise) is dependent on type information that we don't have. Either way, the result is members we know will not be carried over, and others that *might* be. One way or another, this code is broken.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, that variable isn't used, but `cs` throughout this code seems to be an abbreviation of either `csapatsz` or `csapatok`, which are probably the same word in two different cases and/or numbers (I don't actually speak Hungarian).  As abbreviations in variable names go, I have seen far, far worse.

Comment: Added some clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the declaration `int uj_esemeny(meccs m, bajnoksag b)`, `b` is passed to the function by value, meaning only a copy of the caller’s `bajnoksag` is passed to the function.

Within the function, all the statements such as `b.meccsek[b.jatszott++]=m;` change only the copy. They do not change the `bajnoksag` in the calling routine.

To fix this, pass a pointer to a `bajnoksag`:

- Change the function declaration to `int uj_esemeny(meccs m, bajnoksag *b)`.
- Inside the function, change `b.` to `b->`, to refer to the pointed-to structure instead of to the copy.
- Where the function is called, use `&` to pass the address of a `bajnoksag` instead of a copy.

Comment: It works but the test is using
```uj_esemeny(m01,b1)
```
And not &b1
Is it possible without reference?

Comment: @DoppelG: C has pointers. `&b1` is the address of `b1`; it is a pointer to `b1`.

Comment: @DoppelG Are you saying that you are not allowed to change the code that calls this function to read `uj_esemeny(m01, &b1)` instead?

Comment: @zwol thats exactly what i meant

Comment: @DoppelG If you can't change the code that calls this function then the thing you're trying to do is not possible in C.  It _is_ possible in C++, but that's a different programming language, and this program ought to be written completely differently in C++.  You need to talk to your instructor and find out what they actually expect you to do.